# Fast Testing: how to include part of activerecord

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec

When testing a model without loading the entire Rails app, how do I load the bits of Rails that I need?  For instance, I've got a model that contains validations, but I can't figure out how to load active_model/validations.

I tried this:

```
require 'activemodel/lib/active_model/validations'
```

but it throws this error:

```
cannot load such file -- activemodel/lib/active_model/validations
```

I've also tried this:

```
require ActiveModel::Validations
```

But it throws this error:

```
uninitialized constant ActiveModel (NameError)
```

Any idea how I'm supposed to do this?

Comment: pretty close... ```require 'active_model/validations'```

Answer (score 0):

Consider trying [Spork](https://github.com/sporkrb/spork)

Spork preloads Rails, therefore when you run each test, it doesn't have all that lead time.

Here is a screencast with Ryan Bates on how to get spork set up.

http://railscasts.com/episodes/285-spork